# Loop based off user.id

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swig-template

I am using node, express and swig. I want to be able to do a loop based off `currentUser` which is a local variable for me. I got the loop to work but it spits our results for every user.

Here is my loop:

```
{%  for ap in aps  %}
   <tr>
    <td>{{ap.name}}</td>
    <td>{{ap.manufacturer}}</td>
    <td>{{ap.model}}</td>
    <td>{{ap.type}}</td>
    <td>{{ap.notes}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

My partial route (removed parts for other loops):

```
// show model  
  app.get('/dashboard/it/model',
    setRender('dashboard/it/model'),
    setRedirect({auth: '/login'}),
    isAuthenticated,
    (req, res, next) => {
        AP.find({}, function(err, allAP) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.locals.aps = allAP; // Set the data in locals
            }
        });

        Custom.find({}, function(err, allCustom) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);

            } else {
                res.locals.customs = allCustom; // Set the data in locals
                next();
            }
        });

    },
    dashboard.getDefault
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping based off the ID is incorrect and will not work, you need to change the search parameters to filter out by the ID you need to put `"author.id":req.user.id` in where the mongo docs state to put a query param.